# call javascript/ajax function from php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, function, call

i have a little problem here!!

after i submit my form, 
based on php response i want to execute another javascript or ajax function!

this is my form:

```
    <form id="uploadForm" onsubmit="ytVideoApp.prepareSyndicatedUpload( 
    this.videoTitle.value, 
    this.videoDescription.value, 
    this.videoCategory.value, 
    this.videoTags.value); 
    return false;"> 
    Enter video title:<br /> 
    <input size="50" name="videoTitle" type="text" /><br /> 
     Enter video description:<br /> 
    <textarea cols="50" name="videoDescription"></textarea><br /> 
    <select style="display:none" name="videoCategory"> 
    <option style="display:none" value="Music">Music</option> 
    </select> 
    Enter some tags to describe your video 
    <em>(separated by spaces)</em>:<br /> 
    <input name="videoTags" type="text" size="50" value="video" /><br /> 
    <input  id="butok" type="submit" value="go" > 
    </form>
```

on submit run this javascript function

```
 ytVideoApp.prepareSyndicatedUpload = function(videoTitle, videoDescription, videoCategory, videoTags) {
    var filePath = 'operations.php';
    var params = 'operation=makesomething' +
                 '&videoTitle=' + videoTitle +
                 '&videoDescription=' + videoDescription +
                 '&videoCategory=' + videoCategory +
                 '&videoTags=' + videoTags;
    ytVideoApp.sendRequest(filePath, params, ytVideoApp.SYNDICATED_UPLOAD_DIV);
}
```

where ytVideoApp.sendRequest is:

```
ytVideoApp.sendRequest = function(filePath, params, resultDivName) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    var xmlhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    var xmlhr = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
  }

  xmlhr.open('POST', filePath);
  xmlhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 

  xmlhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var resultDiv = document.getElementById(resultDivName);
    if (xmlhr.readyState == 1) {
      resultDiv.innerHTML = '<b>Loading...</b>'; 
    } else if (xmlhr.readyState == 4 && xmlhr.status == 200) {
      if (xmlhr.responseText) {
        resultDiv.innerHTML = xmlhr.responseText;
      }
    } else if (xmlhr.readyState == 4) {
      alert('Invalid response received - Status: ' + xmlhr.status);
    }
  }
  xmlhr.send(params);
}
```

I tried with: `echo "<script>function();</script>"` not working
    print "alert('something');"; not working

any 1 can help me?

thanks!

Comment: This? echo "<script>alert('hello');</script>"

Comment: echo "<script>alert('hello');</script>"; nope

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get what you want be changing:

```
resultDiv.innerHTML = xmlhr.responseText;
```

to:

```
eval(xmlhr.responseText);
```

This is probably a pretty bad idea, but you can do it this way and anything returned from the server will be executed as javascript.

A better solution would be to modify your ajax method so that it takes a callback function rather than an element to update.  It would look more like this:

```
ytVideoApp.sendRequest = function(filePath, params, callback) {
    ...
    } else if (xmlhr.readyState == 4 && xmlhr.status == 200) {
        if(callback) callback(xmlhr.responseText);
    }
    ...
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
ytVideoApp.sendRequest(filePath, params, function(responseText) {
    // Do something with the stuff sent back from the server...
});
```

Better yet...  Use a javascript framework, like jQuery, Prototype, MooTools or YUI.

Comment: if a can recive JSON, i can start a javascript function??

Comment: You can receive JSON and you can pass it to a javascript function.  If you have any control of this project then you should consider using jQuery because it makes this considerably easier.  If you want to return JSON you call jQuery.getJSON, if you want to return and execute javascript then you call jQuery.getScript.